# Can a basis $(v_i)$ of $L^2[0,1]$ satisfy $v_i(0) = v_i'(1) = 0$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Consider the compact operator $S: L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ given by $(L f)(t) = \int_0^t f(s) ds$. We know the adjoint of this operator is defined by $(S^*f)(t) = \int_t^1 f(s) ds$.

Since $S S^*$ is a compact, self-adjoint operator, it has countable eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)$, with eigenspaces $(E_i)$. The closure of the direct sum of its eigenspaces is equal to $L^2[0,1]$, i.e. $\overline{\oplus_i E_i} = L^2[0,1]$ (c.f. [Direct sum of eigenspaces of a compact operator has finite codimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668886/direct-sum-of-eigenspaces-of-a-compact-operator-has-finite-codimension)). Hence the $(v_i)$ form a basis of $L^2[0,1]$.

One can also explicitly compute the orthonormal eigenfunctions $(v_i)$ of $S S^*$ (c.f. [Eigenvalues of the operator $(Tu)(x)=\int_0^x (\int_t^1 u(s)ds)dt.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588628/eigenvalues-of-the-operator-tux-int-0x-int-t1-usdsdt)). However, an element $h \in R(SS^*)$ satisfies $h(0) = 0$ and $h'(1) = 0$, i.e. these functions are restricted at the boundary. Any linear combination $\sum \mu_i v_i$ satisfies these boundary conditions as well. However, this is not the case for general functions $f \in L^2[0,1]$.

I am trying to resolve these seemingly contradictory statements. Does this mean that the $(v_i)$ are a basis for $L^2[0,1]$, despite being tied down at the boundary? And does this then indeed imply that the $L^2$-norm of an arbitrary function $f \in L^2[0,1]$ can be written as $\|f\|_{L^2} = \sum_i \langle f, v_i\rangle^2$?

Comment: You're confusing yourself. A finite linear combination of differentiable functions is differentiable and will have these two constraints. But taking a limit in $L^2$ means asking about $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$ are both entirely meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that in $L^2$ a specific point value does not matter of course since it's only a difference on a null set. I was just wondering if this restricts the limit of linear combinations of these functions. Luckily, it appears that it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-zero trigonometric functions that satisfy
$$
            -f''=\lambda f, \;\; f(0)=0,\; f'(1)=0 \;\;\;\; (\dagger)
$$
form a complete orthogonal subset of $L^2[0,1]$. The reason for this is that $Lf = -f''$ is self-adjoint on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ consisting of all twice absolutely continuous functions $f$ that satisfy $f(0)=0$, $f'(1)=0$. You can check that it is symmetric on this domain because, for all $f,g$ are in $\mathcal{D}(L)$, the following holds:
\begin{align}
     \langle Lf,g\rangle-\langle f,Lg\rangle&=\int_0^1(-f'')g+f(g'')dx \\
      &= \int_0^1(fg'-f'g)'dx \\
      &=(fg'-f'g)|_{0}^{1}=0.
\end{align}
The same is true if you use a complex inner product. It takes a little more to show that $L$ is self-adjoint on $\mathcal{D}(L)$, but it is true.

The values of $\lambda$ for which there is a non-zero solution of $(\dagger)$ are
$$
                       \lambda_n = (n+1/2)^2\pi^2.
$$
and the corresponding eigenfunctions are
$$
                    f_{n}(x)=\sin((n+1/2)\pi x),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The normalized eigenfunctions form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,1]$; so you can expand any $f\in L^2$ in an $L^2$ convergent series
$$
            f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\langle f,f_n\rangle}{\langle f_n,f_n\rangle} f_n
$$
Every basis element $f_n$ satisfies $f_n(0)=f_n'(1)=0$, which is what you want. The series converges in $L^2[0,1]$.