# Operator norm of Fredholm integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

I've decided to ask this question despite the existence of this: [Fredholm operator norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801342/fredholm-operator-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, the answer to which I'm having trouble understanding, and also because I've got a slightly different solution, 90% worked out (I'm struggling with the final part).

Let $k: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and let $K: C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ be defined as $$K(f)(x)=\int_{0}^{1} k(x, t)f(t)dt.$$
It's trivial to see that $K$ is a continuous linear map in the normed vector space $(C[0,1], ||\cdot||_{\infty})$. Prove that its norm is $$||K||_{\infty}=\max_{x \in [0, 1]} \int_{0}^{1} |k(x, t)|dt.$$

It is trivial to show that, due to $|\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|dx$, $$||K||_{\infty} \leq \max_{x \in [0,1]} \int_{0}^{1} |k(x, t)|dt.$$

For the other inequality: since $k$ is continuous on a compact set, there exists an $a \in [0,1]$ such that $$\int_{0}^{1} |k(a, t)|dt = \max_{x \in [0,1]} \int_{0}^{1} |k(x, t)|dt.$$

Then, it suffices to prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a continuous function $f_{\varepsilon}$ with $||f_{\varepsilon}||_{\infty} = 1$ and $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0_{+}} \int_{0}^{1} k(a, t)f_{\varepsilon}(t)dt = \int_{0}^{1} |k(a, t)|dt. $$

Now, since $[0,1]$ is compact, we can partition the interval by $0=t_{0}< t_{1} < \cdot \cdot \cdot < t_{n} = 1$ so that the oscillation of of the function $t \mapsto k(a, t)$ is $< \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ on every partition interval $[t_{i}, t_{i+1}]$. Denote by $P_{1}$ the set of partition intervals where $k(a, \cdot)$ does not change signs, and $P_{2}$ the partition intervals where $k(a, \cdot)$ changes signs. Trivially, for all $t \in I \in P_{2}$, $|k(a, t)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$.

Finally, define $f_{\varepsilon} := sgn \space k(a, t)$ for $t \in I \in P_{1}$, and on $P_{2}$, we draw "straight lines" between two consecutive, disconnected $P_{1}$ intervals so that $f_{\varepsilon}$ remains continuous. On $P_{1}$, we have $k(a, t) f_{\varepsilon}(t) = k(a, t)sgn \space k(a, t) = |k(a, t)|$. What remains to be proven, probably using $|k(a, t)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ on $P_{2}$, and what I can't figure out, is that $$ |\sum_{I \in P_{2}} \int_{I} k(a, t)f_{\varepsilon}(t)dt - \sum_{I \in P_{2}} \int_{I} |k(a, t)|dt|$$ becomes infinitely small as $\varepsilon$ becomes infinitely small.

I would appreciate any help or clarification of this last part, particularly the nature of $f_{\varepsilon}$ on $P_{2}$, or a different solution altogether.

**EDIT:** I think I've figured out the solution: we know that on $P_{2}$, $k(a, t) \in [-\frac{\varepsilon}{4}, \frac{\varepsilon}{4}]$ and $f_{\varepsilon}(t) \in [-1, 1]$, so $$ |\sum_{I \in P_{2}} \int_{I} k(a, t)f_{\varepsilon}(t)dt - \sum_{I \in P_{2}} \int_{I} |k(a, t)|dt| \leq |\sum_{I \in P_{2}} \int_{I} k(a, t)f_{\varepsilon}(t)dt| + |\sum_{I \in P_{2}} \int_{I} |k(a, t)|dt| < \sum_{I \in P_{2}} \int_{I} |k(a, t)||f_{\varepsilon}(t)|dt + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} \leq \sum_{I \in P_{2}} \int_{I} |k(a, t)|dt + \frac{\varepsilon}{4} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$

Comment: If you find $f\in\mathcal{C[0, 1]}$, such that $||f||_\infty = 1$ and $\int_{0}^{1} |k(a, t)|dt < \int_{0}^{1} k(a, t)f(t)dt$, this means that $||K|| \geq \int_{0}^{1} k(a, t)f(t)dt >\int_{0}^{1} |k(a, t)|dt $, which is not what you are trying to prove.

Comment: By definition, $||K|| = sup_{||f||=1} max_{x \in [0, 1]} | \int_{0}^{1} k(x, t)f(t)dt|$, so if I find a family of functions $\{f_{\varepsilon}\}_{\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{+}}$ s.t. the aforementioned inequality holds, I'll have $||K|| \geq \int_{0}^{1} |k(a, t)|dt = max_{x \in [0,1]} \int_{0}^{1} |k(x, t)|dt$, by letting $\varepsilon \to 0_{+}$. By the way, $ ||K|| \geq \int_{0}^{1} |k(a, t)| dt$ is exactly what I'm trying to prove.

Comment: If:) I think you cannot find a single such function: $||K||\geq||Kf||\geq |(Kf)(a)| \geq (Kf)(a)= \int_{0}^{1} k(a, t)f(t)dt >\int_{0}^{1} |k(a, t)|dt =: M$, but you are trying to prove that $||K|| = M$.

Comment: Oh, I see. What a silly mistake. Does that mean the whole solution goes out the window, or is there maybe a way to prove that this family of integrals actually tends to $\int_{0}^{1} |k(a, t)| dt$ as $\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: I think I've edited the question in such a way that it makes sense again. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I think that the answer to the question you gave a link to, precisely answers your question. Maybe, you can precisely state, which part you cannot understand. Anyways, good luck, srečko:)