# Calculate the operator norm of $A: L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ defined by $(Af)(x):=i\int_0^x f(t)\,dt-\frac{i}{2} \int_0^1 f(t) \,dt$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I want to calculate the operator norm of the operator $A: L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ which is defined by $$(Af)(x):=i\int\limits_0^x f(t)\,dt-\frac{i}{2} \int\limits_0^1 f(t)\, dt$$

I've already shown that this operator is compact and selfadjoint. I think maybe this helps me calculating the operator norm. Maybe through spectral theorem for compact self adjoint operators.

I also know that for integral operators of the form
$$(Kf)(x)=\int\limits_0^1 k(x,t) f(t)\,dt$$ the inequality $\Vert K \Vert \leq \Vert k \Vert{}_{L^2}$ holds.

For
$$(Af)(x)=i\int\limits_0^x f(t)\,dt-\frac{i}{2} \int\limits_0^1 f(t) \,dt = \int\limits_0^1 i\,\left(1_{[0,x]}(t)-\frac{1}{2}\right)f(t)\,dt$$ this gives me an upper bound:

$$\Vert A \Vert \leq \left\Vert  i~1_{[0,x]}-\frac{i}{2} \right\Vert{}_{L^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Can someone help me?

Comment: I tried finding a function $f$ such that $\Vert Af \Vert = \frac{1}{2}$ this would give me $\Vert A \Vert =\frac{1}{2}$. But I couldn't find one. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\lvert \langle u,v\rangle \rvert \le \| u \| \| v\|$ gives equality when $u = \alpha v$ for some constant $\alpha$.

Comment: @User8128 Thank you for your response. Can you tell me on which expression you apply Cauchy Schwarz?
I guess the function $f$ which I mentioned in my previous comment is determined by the condition for equality for C.S.?

Comment: I assume you calculated $\|A\|$ using CS: $$\| A \| = \sup_{\|f \|_{L^2} \le 1} \int^1_0 (i\mathbf{1}_{[0,x]} - \tfrac i 2) f(t) dt \le \sup_{\|f\|_{L^2}\le 1} \|i\mathbf{1}_{[0,x]} - \tfrac i 2\|_{L^2} \| f\|_{L^2} \le  \|i\mathbf{1}_{[0,x]} - \tfrac i 2\|_{L^2} = \tfrac 1 2.$$ To make this into an equality, choose the $f$ so that $\|A(f)\|_{L^2} = \tfrac 1 2$; this amounts to choosing $f$ in the first inequality which produces an equality. The first inequality is just Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @User8128 But all your expressions after the first equality are still dependent on $x$, aren't they?
Also for the equality we have to choose the function $f = \alpha (i~1_{[0,x]}(t)-\frac{i}{2})$  so $f$ would also depend on both $x$ and $t$.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I assume $x$ is just some fixed value, otherwise I’m confused what the question is asking; in any case, while the operator does depend on $x$, it will have the same norm for any $x\in [0,1]$ since $i1_{[0,x]}-\frac i 2$ has norm $1/2$ for any such $x$. The variable $t$ is just the variable that the function $f$ transforms. You could replace that $t$ with whatever variable name you want, but of course $f$ is a function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: But the operator $A$ doesn't depend on $x$ the image $Af$ of a function $f \in L^2[0,1]$ does. And yes I know that I can replace this with whatever variable name I want.

In my opinion the following is the case:
$\Vert A \Vert = sup_{\Vert f \Vert_{L^2} \leq 1} \Vert A(f) \Vert_{L^2} = sup_{\Vert f \Vert_{L^2} \leq 1} (\int_0^1 \lvert A(f)(x) \lvert^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}} = sup_{\Vert f \Vert_{L^2} \leq 1} (\int_0^1 \lvert 
\int_0^1 i (1_{[0,x]} - \frac{1}{2}) f(t) dt \lvert^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}} $

Comment: Ohhh, my apologies. I didn't read the problem nearly closely enough, and I was under the impression that $A$ was a functional for each fixed $x$. I see the confusion. The same approach still works, I will add an answer shortly.

Comment: Alternatively: there is a perfectly good answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801342/fredholm-operator-norm?noredirect=1&lq=1) which shows that the operator $Kf(x) = \int^1_0 k(x,t)f(t)dt$ has norm $\|K \| = \sup_{x} \int^1_0 \rvert k(x,t) \lvert dt$ which exactly what you need.

Comment: @User8128 Thanks for your help! I posted an answer to my question below with a different approach. I was sceptical about the link you sent me because there are looking at $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm. But the link helped because, in the beginning it says that the norm of the kernel don't need to coincide with the norm of the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenfunctions of the operator $A$ form an orthonormal system, therefore we can write:
$$Af = \sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \lambda_k (f,e_k)e_k$$ Where $\lambda_k = \frac{1}{(2k+1)\pi}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ with the corresponding eigenfunctions $e_k = e^{(2k+1)\pi i}$.
Now we define
$$c:=\max\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(\vert\lambda_k\vert)$$

$$\Vert Af\Vert^2 = \sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \vert \lambda_k (f,e_k) \vert^2\leq c^2\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \vert(f,e_k) \vert^2=c^2 \Vert f \Vert^2$$

Hence, $\Vert A \Vert \leq c$.

For the other direction assume $f=e_0$, the eigenfunction which corresponds to the greatest eigenvalue $\lambda_0$.

$$\Vert Af \Vert^2=\Vert \lambda_0 f\Vert^2 = c^2$$

It follows that $\Vert A \Vert= c$. Where $c=\max\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\Big(\vert\frac{1}{(2k+1)\pi}\vert \Big)=\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: The operator ist compact and self-afjoint. As I remarked in my question I have already shown this.

Answer (score 3):

Let $k(t,x)=i\big(\mathbb{1}(0<t\leq x)-\frac12\big)$ and define the operator $A_k:f\mapsto\int^1_0k(t,x) f(t)\,dt$ in $L_2([0,1])$. As pointed out in the statement of the problem, $A_k$ is compact and self adjoint. Here is a short proof for completeness.

- $A_k$ is compact in $L_2(0,1)$ because  $\int_{[0,1]^2}|K(t,x)|^2\,dt\,dx =\frac14<\infty$.
- To check self-adjointness of $A_K$, notice that
  $$A_Kf(x)=i\Big(\int^x_0f(t)\,dt-\frac12\int^1_0f(t)\,dt\Big)=\frac{i}{2}\Big(\int^x_0 f(t)\,dt-\int^1_x f(f)\,dt\Big)$$
  while
  \begin{aligned}
   A^*_Kf(x)&=\int^1_0\overline{k(x,t)}f(t)\,dt=-i\Big(\int^1_xf(t)\,dt-\frac12\int^1_0f(t)\,dt\Big)\\
  &=\frac{i}{2}\Big(\int^x_0f(t)\,dt-\int^1_xf(t)\,dt\Big)=A_kf(x)
  \end{aligned}

With all these, we have that the spectrum of $A_f$ consists of countable eigenvalues converging to $0$ (and possibly zero). The larges eigenvalue (in magnitude) is also the norm of $A_k$.

For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the  function $\phi_n(t)=e^{i(2 n + 1)t}$ is an eigenvector of $A_K$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\frac{1}{(2n+1)\pi }$.  At least this gives $\frac{1}{\pi}\leq\|A_K\|\leq 2$. 
**One needs to check that $\{\frac{1}{(2 n+1)\pi}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ are the only eigenvalues**. Once this is verified, it turns out that $\|A_k\|=\frac{1}{\pi}$.

---

A side note: The functions $f_\alpha(t)=\sqrt{2\alpha+1}\,t^\alpha$ with $\alpha>-\frac12$, although they are not eigenfunctions, give an interesting bound:
$\|A_K f_\alpha\|^2_2=\frac{2\alpha+1}{(\alpha+1)^2}\Big(\frac{1}{2\alpha+3}-\frac{1}{\alpha+2}+\frac14\Big)$.
This attains a maximum at $\alpha=0.56807...$ and which gives a lower bound of $0.298225...$ for $\|A_k\|$. That is optimal as $\frac{1}{\pi}=0.3183099...$.